# Eliminar elementos de listas en diccionario

Tags: python, python-2.7, lista, diccionarios

Tengo el siguiente código que es un diccionario con listas dentro.
Lo que quiero hacer es borrar de todas las listas un determinado elemento.

Por ejemplo: borrar todo lo que esté en la posición 2 de cada lista (bici, 2 y C).

```
dicc={}
dicc['lista1']=['coche', 'moto', 'bici', 'avion', 'barco', 'patin']
dicc['lista2']=['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
dicc['lista3']=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
```

Saludos y gracias

Comment: Hola Tercuato, siempre es recomendable que indiques qué has intentado para resolverlo  para evitar eventuales votos negativos o cierres de la pregunta. Itera sobre el diccionario y usa `del lista[indice]` para eliminar el elemento. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

Como ha dicho @FJSevilla, puedes iterar sobre tu diccionario e ir eliminando los elementos de la posición 2.

```
dicc={}
dicc['lista1']=['coche', 'moto', 'bici', 'avion', 'barco', 'patin']
dicc['lista2']=['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
dicc['lista3']=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
INDICE = 2
for i in dicc:
    if len(dicc[i]) < INDICE + 1:
        continue
    dicc[i].pop(INDICE)

print(dicc)
```

Answer (score 1):

Como anteriormente comentaron, si ***un determinado elemento*** es una posición dentro de la lista puedes hacer:

```
 elemento = 2 # Indica el indice
 for k, v in b.items():
    if len(v) > elemento:
        v.pop(elemento)
```

Si ***un determinado elemento*** es un valor contenido en las listas:

```
elemento = "bici" # Indica el valor
for k, v in b.items():
    if elemento in v:
        v.remove(elemento)
```